# css shift effect on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a css effect on hover but that's don't work. I would like that the grey div don't move.

I use bootstrap 3 for the grid with 24px for the gutter (12px on each side).

This effect must be compatible with IE8.

Can I have some help please ?

```
.bgd-effect {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bgd-effect:hover {
  left: 17px;
  right: 8px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the image you have used for your question the solution below is a simple one that will work on multiple different browser's.

CHECK IT OUT HERE: http://codepen.io/jacobg182/pen/Vvebxy

Simply add the following css using a pseudo hover effect:

```
.div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-shadow: 8px 15px 0px #00C2F1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 15px 0px #00C2F1;
  box-shadow: 8px 15px 0px #00C2F1;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Also be sure to add a transition to the div without the pseudo hover state (Just to slow it down so it looks better)

```
.div {
 transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the box-shadow effect work under IE8 ?

Comment: By looking at some articles online, no it doesn't however there are a few work arounds like here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

Comment: With IE8 you will need to do a work arounds like I said previously. You can use a verity of different work arounds one of them is using CSS3 PIE, it's pretty simple to use I hear: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1):

[According to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent), you can use a pseudo element to create a copy and put it in the back.

```
.bgd-effect {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  position:relative;
}
.bgd-effect:before {
  content:"";
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
}
.bgd-effect:hover:before{
  margin:10px;
}
```